# Java Regex pattern, surrounded by multiple strings

Tags: java, regex

This is a continuation of a question I asked earlier. I need to extract a date pattern, which is surrounded by the strings String1, String2, String3 String4. What I did was

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=String1\sString2\s(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d?=\sString3\sString4)");
```

my date pattern is

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\2(19|20)\\d\\d
```

which works fine but when trying to surround it with strings, I am facing trouble.

The date is in between String2 and String3. I am quite sure there is something wrong, as there is an error on my program saying invalid escape sequence but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have an invalid escape sequence:

```
"...(?<=String1\sString..."
               ^^
```

You have to escape the backslash literal in a java String to pass it into a regular expression pattern:

```
"...(?<=String1\\sString..."
               ^^^
```

You already had it right with the `\\d` for digits, but not with the `\\s` for whitespace.

Comment: Is that the only flaw? Ok will try now.

Comment: +1 `\s` is not a valid *java* escape sequence. You are coding a *java* String literal, so you need the double backslash `\\s` to *code* the *regex* `\s`

Comment: Ok I corrected that, but it still does not seem to work. Program generates errors when run. Can someone show me how to extract the date pattern, along with the strings. The strings are specific so no pattern required.

Comment: @newtoprogramming: post the exact error messages. Also, don't only describe the input, also show some real input and the expected output, and we can help you better. You can always use the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18060553/edit) button below your question.

Comment: @jlordo The expected output, should be String1 String2 7/2/2013 String3 String4, which needs to be extracted and copied in an arraylist. The regex, must be matched with an input string, which contains more than a 100 words along with the line of the pattern.

Comment: @newtoprogramming: I think you are trying to overcomplicate things. If your date pattern works, just surround it with the strings, without using any lookahead or -behind.

Comment: @jlordo this is the exact line for which I am trying to write a regex "commented on 7/2/2013 (version1.0)" for which, I tried "commented on (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d (version 1.0)" and also "(?<=commented\\son\\s(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d?=\\s(version 1.0))" neither detects my pattern. Can you help me. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @newtoprogramming: The first one seems to be fine, except you have to escape the brackets and the dot: `"... \\(version 1\\.0\\)"`

Comment: @newtoprogramming: If you found this answer helpful, please don't forget to accept it (green checkmark), so that people know the question has been solved. (Also, you get rep. for accepting).

Comment: @jlordo sorry almost forgot and yes the answer was helpful thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is ending with:

```
\\d?=\sString3\sString4)
```

There it looks like you missed an opening square bracket to make it *positive lookahead* and of course `\s` should be `\\s`. Change that part to:

```
\\d(?=\\sString3\\sString4)
```

Comment: Yes I have changed that. But I do not understand. Should I enclose the whole Regex in Square brackets?

Comment: @newtoprogramming: Why do you want do that? You should now take the time to understand how your pattern works.

Comment: No square brackets are for character class. If you explain your problem clearly we can try to help you.

Comment: @anubhava this is the exact line for which I am trying to write a regex "commented on 7/2/2013 (version1.0)" for which, I tried "commented on (?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d (version 1.0)" and also "(?<=commented\\son\\s(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\\1(?:19|20)?\\d\\d?=\\s(version 1.0))" neither detects my pattern. Can you help me. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide this code in your question as it is very difficult to read from comment.

Answer (score 1):

I know that many people are not aware of the features of the wonderful class `MessageFormat`, so here a quick reminder:

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("String1 String2 {0,date} String3 String4");
try {
    Object[] parse = format.parse("String1 String2 31.8.2000 String3 String4");
    Date date = (Date) parse[0];
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```